# Question About Indices of Alternating Tensors

Tags: tensors, differential-forms

So, with an alternating $k$-tensor, $T^{\sigma} = (-1)^{\sigma}T$. But does that mean $T^{\sigma}(v_1, \cdots, v_k) = (-1)^{\sigma}T(v_1, \cdots, v_k)$ or does it mean $T^{\sigma}(v_1, \cdots, v_k) = (-1)^{\sigma}T(v_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}, \cdots, v_{\sigma^{-1}(k)})$. I have not been able to find a clear answer in my textbook or looking online, and want to make sure I'm understanding correctly. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $T^{\sigma} = (-1)^{\sigma}T$? Is $T$ a tensor and you're defining a new tensor $T^{\sigma}$? Is there a tensor $T^{\sigma}$ for every $\sigma \in  S_k$ or is there supposed to be a single alternating tensor?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese There is a tensor for every $\sigma \in S_k$ that is defined from $T$.

Comment: Where did you find this definition of $T^{\sigma}$? As written, it means the first thing you wrote, i.e. for an even permutation $T^{\sigma} = T$ and for an odd permutation $T^{\sigma} = -T$. Another interpretation is that $T$ is a tensor and we define a new tensor $T^{\sigma}$ by $T^{\sigma}(v_1, \dots, v_k) = T(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots, v_{\sigma(k)})$ and then if $T$ is alternating, we conclude that $T^{\sigma} = (-1)^{\sigma}T$. Maybe this is what is meant?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese What you said as "another interpretation" is what I meant. I'm just confused on what happens with what the tensor inputs with $T^{\sigma} = (-1)^{\sigma}T$.

Comment: If you define $T^{\sigma}$ as I did, then $T^{\sigma} = (-1)^{\sigma}T$ means $T^{\sigma}(v_1, \dots, v_k) = (-1)^{\sigma}T(v_1, \dots, v_k)$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to summarise the discussion in the comments.

Suppose $T$ is a $(0, k)$-tensor, then for any $\sigma \in S_k$ we define a new $(0, k)$-tensor $T^{\sigma}$ by $T^{\sigma}(v_1, \dots, v_k) := T(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(k)})$. If $T$ is alternating, then we have

$$T^{\sigma}(v_1, \dots, v_k) = T(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(k)}) = (-1)^{\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)}T(v_1, \dots, v_k)$$

so $T^{\sigma} = (-1)^{\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)}T$. In particular, if $\sigma$ is an even permutation, then $T^{\sigma} = T$, and if $T$ is an odd permutation, then $T^{\sigma} = -T$.